# Props are empty using useNode from craftjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I have a component in my `craftjs` builder that need to fetch data, and pass it as props to use data in the settings panel, and in the component.

My `fetch` request works fine by itself, but my prop is empty when I `log` it.

I don't understant why, since my request is asynchronous.

Here is the component :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNode } from "@craftjs/core";
import fetchAPI from "@utils/fetch/api";

export const SocialMedia = ({ ...props }) => {
  const {
    connectors: { connect, drag },
  } = useNode();

  console.log(props)

  return (
    <div {...props} ref={(ref) => connect(drag(ref))} className={classNames}>
      // render my links here
    </div>
  );
};

const SocialMediaSettings = () => {
  const {
    actions: { setProp },
  } = useNode((node) => ({
    setProp: node.setProp,
  }));

  getSocialMediaLinks = async () => {
    const response = await fetchAPI("/social_medias", "GET");
    const { id, ...links } = response[0];

    setProp((props) => ({ ...props, socialLinks: links }));

    return links;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getSocialMediaLinks();
  }, []);

  return <>
      // will render my settings here
   </>;
};

export const SocialMediaDefaultProps = {
  socialLinks: {},
};

SocialMedia.craft = {
  props: { ...SocialMediaDefaultProps },
  related: {
    settings: SocialMediaSettings,
  },
};
```

Comment: Could you create a https://codesandbox.io for it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the prop inside of your settings component you pass an object to the function:

```js
setProp((props) => ({ ...props, socialLinks: links }));
```

However, the craft.js documentation shows the `setProp` method setting through direct access and manipulation of the props object received by the function argument to `setProp` as shown [here](https://craft.js.org/docs/concepts/user-components#related-components).

```js
setProp(prop => prop.fontSize = e.target.value)
```

You should modify your invocation of `setProp`:

```
setProp((props) => (props.socialLinks = links));
```

---

Also, be sure your related settings component is rendering, like so in this [documentation](https://craft.js.org/docs/guides/basic-tutorial#settings-panel-1). Likewise, you may consider simply not loading data this far into the component tree—it may be considered more conventional to load the data from a higher-order or root component, both from a React perspective, as well as seemingly being the method craft.js employs in this [example](https://craft.js.org/docs/guides/save-load-state), where the data is loaded using `useEffect` and persisted via `useState` at the `App` level compoenent.